# Pattern matching in perl & assigning

Tags: perl

I need to search for a particular string in a file and then assign it to a variable, example: in the file content it is written as `CURRENT_RUN_ID=1636`, so I need to search for string `CURRENT_RUN_ID` and assign its given value i.e. `1636` to`a variable say`runvar`, for this I tried below given, but it doesn't seem to be working, can you correct me here?

```
opendir(DAPATH,$sDAPATH) or die "Can't open $sDAPATH: $!"; 
print OUTLOG "\nfound da path : $sDAPATH\n"; 
my @adirs = readdir(DAPATH); 
print  OUTLOG "Starting capturing DA\n";
my $da = glob "*$runVar.csv*";
print  OUTLOG "Assigned DA";
closedir(DAPATH);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are not matching any of the lines while performing the pattern matching in line 18. And even you can reduce few repetitive steps in the code.
But for your convenience I have used your program.

```
#!C:\Strawberry\perl\bin
use strict;
use warnings;
my $sSuccessString = "CURRENT_RUN_ID"; 
open(LOG,"$slogfile") or die("Can't open $slogfile\n");
my $sLines;
{
local $/ = undef;
$sLines=<LOG>;
}
    if($sLines =~ m/$sSuccessString/){
    open(OUTLOG, ">>test.txt");
    print OUTLOG "found current run id in log\n";
    print OUTLOG "it is found in log as : $sSuccessString \n";
    #if ($sLines =~ m/(CURRENT_RUN_ID=.*)/i) {
    #print OUTLOG "<p>" . $1 . "<\/p>\n";
 #In below line you need to match the pattern with the line.
    if ($sLines=~/CURRENT_RUN_ID=(.*)/){   
    print OUTLOG "we can now assign run id\n";
    my $runVar = $1;
    print "$runVar\n";      
    print OUTLOG  "assigned current run id to variable\n";
    }
    else {
    print "run id not assigned\n";
    }
    }
```

I have copied your log file content to one of my text file (prog.txt) on my desktop and ran the script. Please see the output.

```
 #!C:\Strawberry\perl\bin
 use strict;
 use warnings;
 my $sSuccessString = "CURRENT_RUN_ID"; 
 open(LOG,"Prog.txt") or die("Can't open text file\n");
 my $sLines;
 {
 local $/ = undef;
 $sLines=<LOG>;
 }
    if($sLines =~ m/$sSuccessString/){
    open(OUTLOG, ">>test.txt");
    print OUTLOG "found current run id in log\n";
    print OUTLOG "it is found in log as : $sSuccessString \n";
    #if ($sLines =~ m/(CURRENT_RUN_ID=.*)/i) {
    #print OUTLOG "<p>" . $1 . "<\/p>\n";
    if ($sLines=~/CURRENT_RUN_ID=(.*)/){
    print OUTLOG "we can now assign run id\n";
    my $runVar = $1;
    print "$runVar\n";      
    print OUTLOG  "assigned current run id to variable\n";
    }
    else {
    print "run id not assigned\n";
    }
    }
```

**OUTPUT**:
      C:\Users\hclabv\Desktop>perl run1.pl

```
1637
```

And my log file (test.txt) where we are capturing the logs while running script is as below.

```
found current run id in log
it is found in log as : CURRENT_RUN_ID 
we can now assign run id
assigned current run id to variable
```

For getting runVar.csv file from desired directory, I have added the below piece of code with in the if loop

```
opendir(DAPATH,"C:/Users/hclabv/Desktop/Scripting/files") or die "Can't open    DAPATH: $!"; 
    print OUTLOG "\nfound da path : DAPATH\n"; 
    my @adirs = readdir(DAPATH);
    print "csv files @adirs\n"; 
    print  OUTLOG "Starting capturing DA\n";
    my $csvfile = "$runVar.csv";
    foreach my $adirs (@adirs) {
          if ($adirs eq $csvfile) {
          print "file found\n";
          my $da = $adirs;      
          print "csv file is $da\n";
    }
    print  OUTLOG "Assigned DA";
    close(DAPATH); 
    }
```

Comment: @STJ please mark as answer if your issue is solved with this solution.

Comment: Amareesh, @Arunesh, I need to collect one file as in variable and that file name contains this run id, for that i went to that file location and am using this: my $da = glob "*$runVar.csv*";  but this also doesn't seems to be working accurately, can you please help me through.

Comment: @STJ Please post your script which you have tried in your question and what exactly you require. Do you want to get the file that contains this runid in its name in a particular directory?

Comment: Exactly, I want to capture one file that contains this runid in its name and need  that file to be mailed, however mailing part is completed i here just need to capture one file which has its name that "runVar.csv". Added script portion in question.

Comment: Exactly, I want to capture one file that contains this runid in its name and need that file to be mailed, however mailing part is completed i here just need to capture one file which has its name that "runVar.csv". Added script portion in question

Comment: @STJ I have added that piece of code to my answer above at the end. I just have few csv files with several numbers in a directory that I have mentioned for testing and it worked. I have added that piece of code in the if loop.

Answer (score 1):

It is not matching because you are giving spaces at `if (/CURRENT_RUN_ID = \s*(.*)/)` in the match.It is searching for spaces  in the string.

The pattern what you are trying to match will match `CURRENT_RUN_ID = 1636`  string, notice the spaces between `CURRENT_RUN_ID` and `=` and after `=`. If there  is match then the no of spaces in the pattern should be exactly same as the no of spaces in the string.

There is space between `CURRENT_RUN_ID` and `=` and also after `=`.
Better remove the faulty spaces  and make the space optional using `\s*` try this:

```
if (/CURRENT_RUN_ID\s*=\s*(.*)/){ 
 my $runvar = $1;
 print "$runvar \n";  
}
```

EDIT:

As per your requirement I changed your script as(I am not writing to file):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
open my $fh, '<', 'file' or die "unable to open file : $! \n";
my $runVar="";
while(<$fh>){
      if (/CURRENT_RUN_ID\s*=\s*(.*)/){
        print  "we can now assign run id\n";
        $runVar = $1;
        print   "assigned current run id to variable\n";
        }
       else {
       print  "run id not assigned\n";
      }
}
close($fh);
```

Comment: Hi Arunesh, with this also am getting error saying "use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//)", do you need to know any other detail.

Comment: I have added the snippet in the question: when am using the commented part, it is printing it correctly. Also apologies, as there is no space before and after =.

Comment: @STJ you should also include your sample file input in question.

Comment: Arunesh, are you talking about the file which is used in open(), if that is so why it is required since open is working fine, also the code is going finely till first if() and able to search for CURRENT_RUN_ID as it is getting printed in next 2  prints,  the problem is only in assigning its value to variable, Please let me know if you want to know anything else

Comment: Actually you are slurping the whole file in variable.Read line by line you don't need to do that.
Thats y I just needed 5-10 sample lines to refer to file.

Comment: Added as file snippet

Comment: refering to your file I see there are many lines which doesn't contain `CURRENT_RUN_ID` do you wish to `print` `run id not assigned\n` for each of them.Means that will be redundant, although check my edit.